# Idiomatic way to get correct result messages from std::io

Tags: rust

I continue to try Rust, and there is one issue.
I want to have useful messages from `std::io`, for example when I'm trying to open file I want to get `<file_name>` in `Err(err)` case, but it isn't there, for example:

```
fn read_to_string(file_name: &str) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    let data = fs::read_to_string(file_name);
    // let data = Ok(fs::read_to_string(file_name).expect(("Can not read file ".to_string() + file_name + "\n").as_str()));

    return data;
}
```

And return message is:

```
[src/main.rs:26] res = Os {
    code: 2,
    kind: NotFound,
    message: "No such file or directory",
}
```

Without any `<file_name>` - this is so strange that I suspect that I'm doing something wrong. `<file_name>` is the data I want the most.

So what the right (or idiomatic) way in Rust to get this `<file_name>` output?

**Note 1**: Yes there are logging, but it isn't always possible - suppose you traverse `file_system` from some point, or if it is possible - you should write parser to get enough information.

**Note 2**: Commented code (with `expect(...)` function) - can give me needed information, this is the most upsetting thing in this situation.

Comment: you can check some open source projects on github to see the coding style in rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's been [some discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2885) about possibly adding paths to built-in IO operations, but for now you can just map the error with a message that includes the filename:

```rust
fn read_to_string(file_name: &str) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    fs::read_to_string(file_name).map_err(|e| {
        std::io::Error::new(
            e.kind(),
            format!("Error while reading file {}: {}", file_name, e),
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with using external crates, [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) allows you to attach arbitrary information to any error, and keep the complete track of the full error stack:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use std::fs;

fn read_file (name: &str) -> Result<String> {
    Ok (fs::read_to_string (name)
        .with_context (|| format!("Could not read file {name}"))?)
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let contents = read_file ("unknown_file.txt")
        .context ("Could not get file contents")?;
    println!("File contents: {contents}");
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2500ad6718b290ebd535f67eaf8ffc4e)

Prints:

```
Error: Could not get file contents

Caused by:
    0: Could not read file unknown_file.txt
    1: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `.with_context(|| format!(...))` to lazily create the string, so you don't allocate on the `Ok` case. Also instead of `Ok(expr?)`, you can just use `expr` in this case.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues good point, I'll fix it

Comment: Also your playground link is wrong, it links to an unrelated snippet.